# Jasper Reports - how to get column footer to appear directly below details band

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to get a column footer band to appear directly below a details band.

The details band contains normally just 2 or 3 rows and thus should not be very deep. The footer always appears further down the page and not directly below the end of the content in the details band - therefore the details band is higher than the content it contains. How do I get the details band to collapse to the end of the content so I can get the footer to appear immediately afterwards.

I'm sure this is simply a case of applying some settings - but I can't determine what these are.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you designing/defining the report? I've found that unless you use something like [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport), it's really hard to do this kind of tuning. With that tool, you can shrink the bands and remove the extra space in your defined reports. You can also add/remove bands with iReport.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the feedback. I'm using iReport. How do I remove the extra space? On the designer it looks like there is no space as I've decreased the widths of the bands in question. But the resulting PDF still contains the white space.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In iReport set `Ignore pagination` to true in your main report's properties.

This should cause your footer to be render at the bottom of the content in your details band.

Comment: I've realised that I need to cater for a report that goes over more than one page. So 'Ignore pagination' is no longer appropriate. However I've found the setting above it in the properties window 'Float column footer' places the footer directly below the details band on each page. Perfect!  Hope this helps someone else somewhere down the line.

Comment: @Peanut: Thanks. It helped me too. But it appears after the `Summary band`. It's another problem for me. Can you give me a solution please?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds very strange, true it will work since report does **not** have pages anymore, but if you export to pdf what will happen?, I would take a look at [Agus answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9066292/5292302), that's the correct way to determine where the column footer is placed.

Comment: @mmcrae Yes this is not correct answer anymore (fow newer report versions, maybe it worked back then in 2010), now you should use "Float column footer" which can be found when you click generally on report under properties tab

Answer (score 33):

You can try to set ***Column Footer Placement*** property. It is solved for me.

The quote from the *JasperReports Ultimate Guide*:

```
Column Footer Placement - The isFloatColumnFooter Boolean property lets users customize 
the behavior of the column footer section. By default, this section is rendered at 
the bottom of the page, just above the page footer. In certain cases, it is useful 
to render it higher on the page, just below the last detail or group footer on 
that  particular column. To do this, set the isFloatColumnFooter property to true.
```

Comment: how does setting it to true determine which of those last - 3 - options?

Comment: That depends on the bands you are using. Considering ``Float Column Footer`` is checked: If you don't have any groups then it will be placed directly below the last ``detail`` entry in the detail band. If you have groups with footers is will be placed directly under the last group footer.

Answer (score 13):

Set "Float column footer" property of report is better than "ignore pagination" in case that you want to keep format of page. There is shrink of view (for example PDF in not in A4 format) in case of ignore pagination. "float column footer" keeps format of page.

Comment: right - choosing "ignore pagination" makes it so the PDF is just one page, no bottom margins or anything

Answer (score 7):

For those, who don't use reporting tool (JasperSoft or older iReport) and directly work with XML, add `isFloatColumnFooter` to the `<jasperReport>` element.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jasperReport PUBLIC "//JasperReports//DTD Report Design//EN"
   "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/dtds/jasperreport.dtd">

<jasperReport xmlns = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
              xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation = "http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports
   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
              isFloatColumnFooter="true"
              name="report2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="230" 
              columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20"
              topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

...
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

Float column footer is the right setting here.
If you still have space lost between the output of the detail band and te footer take care about other bands wasting space, like the summary does. If you don't need that bands remove them or set theit height to 0.