# Remove additional whitespace from HTML report in JasperReports

Tags: html, jasper-reports

How do I remove the additional block of white space from the bottom in a HTML report which has records less than a page?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233495/jasper-reports-how-to-get-column-footer-to-appear-directly-below-details-band/3235472

It is similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, false);

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> iReport -> JasperReports Properties  and set the "net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.using.images.to.align" property to false.
If this doesn't work, there are a few more properties around the above property. You can check them too.

Comment: Nope! that does not work. That only removes the nullpx image being added to the HTML report. I've tried setting/unsetting other properties too. The HTML report looks perfectly fine for pages with full data, it looks bad only for pages that do not have data till the end.