# Best way to place some data directly below the "Detail 1 Bar" in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm designing a report template using iReport tool.

The requirement is simply to have a table full of data and at the end (just after the last row of data) displaying the totals of that data.

So far I designed like below.

[image]

But I still don't know whether it's correct to put those data in Column footer or not.

And I'm using `isIgnorePagination="true"` so there won't be any pages but a single page of data with large amount of data records.

Is there any way I can have the pagination back. I can't remove the `isIgnorePagination="true"` because then there will be a gap between Detail Bar and Column Footer if there is less data to display and if there are multiple pages that column footer data will display for each page. (I need that totals to display just after the table data)

Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasper Reports - how to get column footer to appear directly below details band](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233495/jasper-reports-how-to-get-column-footer-to-appear-directly-below-details-band)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the column footer will be set directly over the page footer, as you have seen.

The option `Float Column Footer`, if set to `true`, will let the column footer float directly under the detail bar and *not* anchored over the page footer (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233495/jasper-reports-how-to-get-column-footer-to-appear-directly-below-details-band)).

Comment: it's better if you suggest as duplicate, but thanks for your effort in answering jasper-reports question, we sure need some backup here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, happy to be here. Still trying to sort things out here on SO...

Comment: No worries, if you need anything you can find me in the chat rooms (see profile), I'm happy to help you out since we need help in jasper-reports.